# Almost sure convergence in terms of sets

Tags: probability-theory, convergence-divergence, random-variables

Let $(\Omega,\mathcal{F},p)$ be a probability space, and let $X_n$ be a sequence of random variables.
Suppose that for a random variable $X$ we have that for all events $F\in\mathcal{F}$,
$$
\lim_{n\to\infty}\int_F X_n \, dp = \int_F X \, dp .
$$
Can we conclude that $X_n\to X$ almost surely?

Comment: Yes. Thanks, corrected.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, this doesn't hold. In fact, it holds iff $(\Omega,\mathcal{F},p)$ is "essentially" discrete.

For example, let $\Omega=[0,1)$, let $\mathcal{F}$ be the Borel $\sigma$-algebra, and let $p$ be Lebesgue measure. Let $$G_{n,k}=\Bigl[\frac{k-1}{n},\frac{k}{n}\Bigr)$$ for $n=1,2,\ldots$ and $1\leqslant k\leqslant n$. Let $F_1,F_2,\ldots$ be the numeration of the collection $G_{n,k}$ given by $$F_1,F_2,F_3,F_4,F_5,F_6,\ldots = G_{1,1},G_{2,1},G_{2,2},G_{3,1},G_{3,2},G_{3,3},\ldots.$$ In other words, with $s_0=0$ and $$s_n=\sum_{i=1}^n i$$ for $n=1,2,\ldots$, each $m\in\mathbb{N}$ admits a unique decomposition of the form $m=s_{n-1}+k$ where $n\in\{0\}\cup \mathbb{N}$ and $1\leqslant \leqslant n$.   Then $F_m=G_{n,k}$. In particular, $p(F_m)\leqslant 1/n$ whenever $m>s_{n-1}$.

Let $X_n$ be the indicator of $F_n$ and let $X=0$. Then $$\lim_n \int_F X_ndp = \lim_n p(F_n\cap F)=0.$$ However, for each $x\in [0,1)$ and $n=1,2,\ldots$, there exists a unique $k_n(x)\in [1,n]$ such that $x\in G_{n,k_n(x)}=F_{s_{n-1}+k_n(x)}$. For $n>1$, let $l_n(x)\in [1,n]$ be distinct from $k_n(x)$. Then $$X_{s_{n-1}+k_n(x)}(x)=1$$ and $$X_{s_{n-1}+l_n(x)}(x)=0$$ for all $n=2,3,\ldots$. Therefore $X_n$ is not pointwise convergent at any point.

More generally, say $F\in \mathcal{F}$ is an **atom** if $p(F)>0$ and for any $G\in\mathcal{F}$ with $G\subset F$, either $p(G)=0$ or $p(G)=p(F)$.  Let $(F_i)_{i\in I}$ be a maximal collection of pairwise disjoint atoms. Such a maximal collection exists by Zorn's lemma. Note that a maximal collection of atoms might be empty.

I claim that $I$ is countable. That's because, since $p(F_i)>0$ for all $i\in I$, $I=\bigcup_{m=1}^\infty \{i\in I:p(F_i)>1/m\}.$  But since the $F_i$ are pairwise disjoint and $p(\Omega)=1$, $$|\{i\in I:p(F_i)>1/m\}|\leqslant 1/m,$$ so the union, $I$, is countable.

Let $J=\cup_{i\in I}F_i$, which is measurable since $I$ is countable. Let $K=\Omega\setminus J$. If $p(K)>0$, then we can construct a procedure similar to the one above using $K$ to find a sequence of measururable subsets $G_n$ of $K$ such that $\lim_n \int_F 1_{G_n}dp=0$ but $1_{G_n}(x)$ does not converge for any $x\in K$.

On the other hand, if $p(K)=0$, then one can show that if $\lim_n \int_F X_ndp=\int_F Xdp$ for all $F\in\mathcal{F}$, then $X_n\to X$ a.s. In this case, $(\Omega, \mathcal{F},p)$ is "essentially" discrete, being made up of "points" $F_1,F_2,\ldots$.

Answer (score 2):

No: take a sequence $\left(X_n\right)_{n\geqslant 1}$ which converges to $0$ in $\mathbb L^1$ but not almost surely (for example $\left(X_n\right)_{n\geqslant 1}$ i.i.d. with $\mathbb P(X_n=1)=1/n$ and $\mathbb P(X_n=0)=1-1/n$) to get a counter-example.